# Import large table in excel to latex

Tags: tables, longtable

I have converted a large table in excel to latex.  When I put the table in latex, I get part of the table.  How to break up the table to span over two or more pages?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'data'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrr}
    \toprule
    theta\_1 & r2v   & r3v   & x     & y \\
    \midrule
    49.22794 & 0.35873 & 0.39838 & -0.57966 & 0.62744 \\
    36.26729 & 0.06672 & 0.05691 & 0.02389 & 0.70802 \\
    9.63361 & 0.22289 & 0.07941 & 0.29043 & 0.77239 \\
    65.17496 & 0.25439 & 0.17791 & -0.54248 & 0.60032 \\
    55.23141 & 0.26525 & 0.42388 & -0.57985 & 0.48911 \\
    70.46714 & 0.42986 & 0.29139 & -0.79884 & 0.49944 \\
    50.99585 & 0.33886 & 0.29309 & -0.51703 & 0.67857 \\
    73.01872 & 0.40292 & 0.46292 & -0.84462 & 0.29147 \\
    51.90983 & 0.26562 & 0.28754 & -0.46672 & 0.62942 \\
    84.96263 & 0.47795 & 0.00499 & -0.92118 & 0.57311 \\
    78.43069 & 0.03334 & 0.40469 & -0.49459 & 0.19343 \\
    45.6842 & 0.27076 & 0.3044 & -0.41117 & 0.66785 \\
    70.99408 & 0.14083 & 0.23996 & -0.51338 & 0.44658 \\
    42.57276 & 0.24045 & 0.13422 & -0.22848 & 0.78199 \\
    74.59215 & 0.34243 & 0.12905 & -0.70528 & 0.57397 \\
    29.02334 & 0.10413 & 0.2405 & -0.06571 & 0.64299 \\
    87.85319 & 0.30408 & 0.11367 & -0.77924 & 0.41081 \\
    25.03899 & 0.16309 & 0.0243 & 0.15005 & 0.79093 \\
    6.55477 & 0.44042 & 0.08462 & 0.30149 & 0.97119 \\
    67.61012 & 0.0667 & 0.12922 & -0.3754 & 0.55025 \\
    74.80698 & 0.0512 & 0.09896 & -0.4185 & 0.52404 \\
    83.01043 & 0.47956 & 0.30285 & -0.93897 & 0.30871 \\
    29.43219 & 0.07645 & 0.41185 & -0.20593 & 0.5342 \\
    72.36623 & 0.07627 & 0.40531 & -0.51249 & 0.25702 \\
    48.44253 & 0.07778 & 0.40112 & -0.36258 & 0.4469 \\
    41.69654 & 0.04478 & 0.35406 & -0.25049 & 0.49307 \\
    73.86752 & 0.22721 & 0.42969 & -0.67082 & 0.26202 \\
    85.67159 & 0.33445 & 0.39054 & -0.81421 & 0.16638 \\
    6.86456 & 0.41565 & 0.1019 & 0.28204 & 0.94614 \\
    63.7804 & 0.39512 & 0.49667 & -0.79478 & 0.38956 \\
    21.14338 & 0.35636 & 0.04681 & 0.11273 & 0.95104 \\
    35.9006 & 0.2363 & 0.32531 & -0.28843 & 0.68783 \\
    24.1312 & 0.35429 & 0.10759 & 0.00839 & 0.9289 \\
    74.9262 & 0.47903 & 0.12194 & -0.83867 & 0.61224 \\
    89.58364 & 0.25289 & 0.16984 & -0.74051 & 0.33055 \\
    58.47759 & 0.15253 & 0.09893 & -0.34064 & 0.67356 \\
    63.35575 & 0.39491 & 0.25342 & -0.6826 & 0.61276 \\
    83.90729 & 0.11819 & 0.47538 & -0.60268 & 0.08406 \\
    61.88873 & 0.11715 & 0.1973 & -0.39526 & 0.54866 \\
    51.15185 & 0.23235 & 0.29223 & -0.43539 & 0.61102 \\
    34.27628 & 0.30969 & 0.30327 & -0.29194 & 0.76879 \\
    57.11215 & 0.30766 & 0.35732 & -0.59507 & 0.54874 \\
    32.69058 & 0.06131 & 0.20077 & -0.05014 & 0.6229 \\
    36.68575 & 0.0619 & 0.42935 & -0.27707 & 0.4818 \\
    33.18298 & 0.14223 & 0.46024 & -0.31694 & 0.54815 \\
    42.15589 & 0.36787 & 0.37542 & -0.48711 & 0.71621 \\
    45.30725 & 0.20565 & 0.1428 & -0.24683 & 0.73963 \\
    81.94822 & 0.41449 & 0.39841 & -0.88204 & 0.22233 \\
    18.57879 & 0.46756 & 0.07138 & 0.09646 & 1.04262 \\
    30.47433 & 0.19953 & 0.25228 & -0.1405 & 0.71738 \\
    51.67131 & 0.02611 & 0.30534 & -0.28725 & 0.46885 \\
    43.82392 & 0.28559 & 0.3519 & -0.43381 & 0.65866 \\
    23.59971 & 0.37383 & 0.19167 & -0.06787 & 0.91302 \\
    52.16341 & 0.16012 & 0.36434 & -0.4333 & 0.50198 \\
    79.04949 & 0.24647 & 0.44364 & -0.7133 & 0.19032 \\
    5.48552 & 0.11083 & 0.02792 & 0.4075 & 0.64272 \\
    39.67888 & 0.46964 & 0.06911 & -0.28493 & 1.0105 \\
    7.58322 & 0.24115 & 0.43153 & -0.03357 & 0.73313 \\
    50.69139 & 0.27  & 0.21087 & -0.40805 & 0.7013 \\
    48.53795 & 0.11053 & 0.20566 & -0.25845 & 0.61446 \\
    69.12521 & 0.04797 & 0.47957 & -0.49716 & 0.20611 \\
    20.97812 & 0.03008 & 0.37512 & -0.07426 & 0.52853 \\
    52.86256 & 0.40975 & 0.4905 & -0.71456 & 0.5468 \\
    41.30765 & 0.38574 & 0.11676 & -0.29395 & 0.90751 \\
    77.48834 & 0.09785 & 0.04811 & -0.47707 & 0.56362 \\
    59.47525 & 0.44756 & 0.19229 & -0.65387 & 0.73695 \\
    31.84912 & 0.34215 & 0.25014 & -0.23112 & 0.83607 \\
    31.24677 & 0.32842 & 0.28513 & -0.24511 & 0.80857 \\
    22.83463 & 0.49519 & 0.48832 & -0.37617 & 0.91057 \\
    85.72753 & 0.01685 & 0.24643 & -0.48692 & 0.28564 \\
    26.83809 & 0.21213 & 0.20044 & -0.05416 & 0.75948 \\
    14.25655 & 0.24499 & 0.4975 & -0.18342 & 0.71174 \\
    32.51674 & 0.29175 & 0.1305 & -0.11287 & 0.85514 \\
    66.74662 & 0.04163 & 0.33266 & -0.42436 & 0.35904 \\
    63.531 & 0.33008 & 0.48213 & -0.72838 & 0.37704 \\
    63.0803 & 0.02615 & 0.33558 & -0.38805 & 0.37583 \\
    0.56032 & 0.27842 & 0.14959 & 0.33788 & 0.77176 \\
    33.6911 & 0.35601 & 0.26556 & -0.2784 & 0.83119 \\
    81.13461 & 0.24396 & 0.00073 & -0.64901 & 0.60148 \\
    28.65103 & 0.3088 & 0.44189 & -0.3364 & 0.72645 \\
    53.73746 & 0.10689 & 0.20219 & -0.30809 & 0.58915 \\
    26.80157 & 0.32283 & 0.1506 & -0.05911 & 0.8808 \\
    11.25129 & 0.19032 & 0.47529 & -0.11341 & 0.67109 \\
    34.95201 & 0.05186 & 0.23032 & -0.09349 & 0.59575 \\
    73.5919 & 0.18876 & 0.14382 & -0.55191 & 0.52861 \\
    88.30581 & 0.13143 & 0.04231 & -0.60778 & 0.47086 \\
    77.57909 & 0.12064 & 0.29109 & -0.55249 & 0.33048 \\
    7.54388 & 0.31146 & 0.07653 & 0.30962 & 0.84946 \\
    30.39408 & 0.26146 & 0.03655 & 0.01525 & 0.88014 \\
    21.25162 & 0.20662 & 0.29028 & -0.0617 & 0.72345 \\
    28.60248 & 0.1089 & 0.14351 & 0.02189 & 0.69408 \\
    88.60036 & 0.42928 & 0.18096 & -0.91133 & 0.3364 \\
    49.34258 & 0.4305 & 0.36241 & -0.61193 & 0.70032 \\
    67.43261 & 0.14197 & 0.42916 & -0.55831 & 0.30333 \\
    75.76666 & 0.3077 & 0.17396 & -0.69427 & 0.50732 \\
    15.02007 & 0.38974 & 0.48087 & -0.21435 & 0.85335 \\
    81.27878 & 0.47742 & 0.47678 & -0.95348 & 0.16469 \\
    9.46117 & 0.4598 & 0.10302 & 0.23052 & 1.00132 \\
    67.05838 & 0.19241 & 0.38412 & -0.58521 & 0.36811 \\
    65.64347 & 0.08132 & 0.30777 & -0.44325 & 0.40619 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```